# Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035

Tags: flutter

debug console looke like this :

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

if anyone knows how to solve it plz answer me

Comment: Did you add image_picker to your flutter app? Just curious.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue it's generally related to flutter installation and your java environment if it's any of those you have to completely reinstall flutter and also your Android Studio. If this is the first time you running flutter on your desktop then this might be the problem.

But there are some more quick fixes to try out before taking the above measure
Like clearing out cache and stuff or if there's a problem with the minimum SDK version try exporting the code to a new flutter app or updating/downgrading SDK version.